# Connection to SQL Server database slow

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I am connecting to a cloud hosted Microsoft SQL Server database from PHP. I am testing locally, using an Ubuntu server running on Windows WSL.

```php
function connectDB() {
  $server = 'xxx';
  $database = 'xxx';
  $port = 'xxx';
  $uid = 'xxx';
  $pwd = 'xxx';
  
  $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$server,$port;Database=$database;", $uid, $pwd);
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  return $conn;
}

$start_time = microtime(true);
$products = [];
$pdo = connectDB();

$query = '
  SELECT
    p.barcode,
    t.el AS title,
    d.el AS description

  FROM dbo.product p
  LEFT JOIN dbo.prdnames t ON p.barcode = t.id
  LEFT JOIN dbo.prdshortdescriptions d ON p.barcode = d.id
';

$statement = $pdo->query($query);
$db_products = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if ($db_products) {
  foreach ($db_products as $product) {
    $products[] = [
      'slug' => $product['barcode'],
      'content' => [
        'title' => $product['title'],
        'text'  => $product['desc'],
      ]
    ];
  }
}

$end_time = microtime(true);
$execution_time = ($end_time - $start_time);

print_r($products);
echo "<br>" . " Execution time: " . $execution_time;
```

The time it takes to execute the above code is around 2 seconds. The query is very simple, returning 6 rows. Is this time normal? I was expecting it to execute in milliseconds.

If it helps, the queries are executing very fast on Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, but it still takes some seconds to connect to the database server.

Comment: How do you know it's the connection that's slow?

Comment: It's probably not the connection. Please add the SQL query, table and index definitions and share the query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

Comment: @Charlieface I added the query, and created the plan here https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1y9w7Lqu. I don't have experience with databases, how can I share table and index definitions?

Comment: The query plan is poor, with 3 index scans. But it looks like there are only a handful of rows in each table so it probably won't make a difference. Perhaps another query is blocking it? I suggest you check the quality of your network also.